# Windows 10 Laravel Permission denied in package development

Tags: laravel, windows, permissions, package, laravel-package

I am trying to develop my first package in laravel everything was fine until I add my custom route and in my provider, I added this line of code `loadRoutesFrom`

```php
public function boot()
{
   $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../database/migrations');
   $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/../routes/');
}
```

and my sample laravel project which uses this package I get the below error

> require(E:\laragon\www\____\AuthManager\routes): Failed to open
> stream: Permission denied
> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
> .php line 152

*I am using windows 10 and have admin I changed the permission on both projects the same and both projects are under the same directory.*

[image]

Comment: `loadRoutesFrom` takes a path to the route file you want to load, not a directory

Answer (score 0):

as @lagbox mentioned in his comment I should pass the file, not a directory to loadRoutesFrom method.